# Using raw file when trying to make local SQLite database

Tags: android, mp3, android-sqlite, android-mediaplayer, android-resources

Currently I'm working with a SQLite database that will pull `.mp3`s from the device's external memory (like an SD) that stores all the albums content (like album artwork, track name, ect.) in a `MediaPlayer` in my `DataBase`. My goal is to get it to have already preloaded `.mp3`s once the `.apk` is extracted, so I tried to store `.mp3`s in raw to make `R.raw.song` calls but I got errors because my song had capital letters and number, I want tot keep them that way, and I'm not wanting to relabel each one and I want to utilize this `DataBaseHelper`. How can I have preloaded content in my `DataBase` if I keep getting this error?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':audiobook:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/user/Downloads/MaterialAudiobookPlayer/audiobook/src/main/res/raw/102 - Trafalgarsquare.mp3: Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I have preloaded content in my DataBase if I keep getting this error?

This has nothing to do with a database. It has everything to do with valid resource names, and your files do not have valid resource names.

To package arbitrarily-named files in your app, put them in your `assets/` directory and use `AssetManager` to access them.

Or, if you want to keep them as raw resources for easier playback with classes like `MediaPlayer`, rename them to have valid filenames for resources.